# Receive BroadcastReceiver for new event in Calendar?

Tags: android, calendar

Is there a possibility to receive notifications, when a new event is added to the calendar in Android?
I searched for some BroadcastReceivers, walked through new ICS CalendarContract, but no luck.

I used to work with BlackBerry APIs a lot, where Calendar seems to be part of the OS. There you can register your listener for such kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

afaik it not possible in android because in Android calendar is diffrent application. i hava lot of try but still not success to achive.